# C64 assembler - Trying to print 4 rows at the top and the bottom

Tags: assembly, c64

I'm trying to print some rows of a char from the top and bottom, first row turns out as expected but next one doesn't print. I add 40 chars to "Currentline" to get the prog to print the next row, well - that was what I thought would work. It won't print, but if I set "Currentline" to 40 from the start it prints on the next row.

What am I doing wrong?

```
/*
****************************************
* Really awesome code by Cri33e - 2022 * 
****************************************
*/

*=$2000                             // Startas med sys8192


.var ScreenCTop_Adress = $d7ff
.var ScreenCBottom_Adress = $dbbf
.var ScreenTop_Adress = $03ff
.var ScreenBottom_Adress = $07bf

.var Currentline = 0
.var Char_color = 3
.var HowManyRows = 4

Next_row:              
                lda #Char_color
                ldy #20             
                ldx #40             

 loop1:          
                sta ScreenCTop_Adress+Currentline,x     
                sta ScreenCBottom_Adress-Currentline,x 
                tya
                sta ScreenTop_Adress+Currentline,x       
                sta ScreenBottom_Adress-Currentline,x   
                lda #Char_color
                dex
                bne loop1

                lda Currentline + 40  
                sta Currentline        

                ldx HowManyRows       
                dex
                stx HowManyRows
                bne Next_row

rts


enter code here
```

Comment: `lda Currentline + 40` is not how you add 40. That adds the 40 to the address and loads a value from there. You want `lda Currentline; clc; adc #40`

Comment: Then again, that won't work either because you need a true variable for that, and you need to fix all the other additions as well.

Comment: It's not a true variable? How so?

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems:

1. The `.var` directive does not do what you think it does (at least for `Currentline` and `HowManyRows`). I think it's just a preprocessing directive similar to `#define` in C. You should use the `.DB` directive along with a memory label.
2. You cannot do an addition-and-load in the same operation, so (assuming you make the correction suggested in point 1) `lda Currentline + 40` will not do what you think it will. It loads the accumulator with the value from the memory address specified by `Currentline` offset by 40 bytes.
3. Similarly, you cannot do an addition-and-store in the same operation, so , so (assuming you make the correction suggested in point 1) lines like `sta ScreenCTop_Adress+Currentline,x` will not work. It will store the value in the accumulator at the address equal to the `ScreenCTop_Adress` + the *address* of `Currentline` plus the value in X.

Your code needs a significant rewrite in order to make it work, and because screen RAM and colour RAM are larger than 256 bytes each, it can't be done *properly* without using pointers in the zero-page and indirect addressing. However, just for the fun of it I'll attempt a rewrite that *doesn't* use the zero-page, since I don't know what portion of the zero-page is available to you. I'll also try to make it as similar to your code as possible, but a LOT needs to be changed. I warn you, the result will be ugly and by no means the *right* solution. Also, I'm not testing this.

```
; Color RAM base addresses for groups of six character rows
; (i.e. what can be fully addressed with an 8-bit index)
.VAR ScreenC_Address_0_5 = $D800    ; rows 0-5
.VAR ScreenC_Address_6_11 = $D8F0   ; rows 6-11
.VAR ScreenC_Address_12_17 = $D9E0  ; rows 12-17
.VAR ScreenC_Address_18_23 = $DAD0  ; rows 18-23
.VAR ScreenC_Address_24 = $DBC0     ; row 24
                                  
; Screen RAM base addresses for groups of six character rows
; (i.e. what can be fully addressed with an 8-bit index)                 
.VAR Screen_Address_0_5 = $0400    ; rows 0-5
.VAR Screen_Address_6_11 = $04F0   ; rows 6-11
.VAR Screen_Address_12_17 = $05E0  ; rows 12-17
.VAR Screen_Address_18_23 = $06D0  ; rows 18-23
.VAR Screen_Address_24 = $07C0     ; row 24

; this is what you are filling your line with
; these are constants - you need to reassemble to change them
; an alternative is to store these in memory and set then set 
; them in code before calling the function   
.VAR Char_color = 3                ; color constant (cyan)
.VAR CharVal = $20                 ; fill character display code (space)

CurrentLine:    .DB 0                      ; first row number to fill
HowManyRows:    .DB 4                      ; count of rows to fill at top and bottom
MirrorCount:    .DB                        ; so code doesn't have to be duplicated for top/bottom halves

Next_row:       LDA #2
                STA MirrorCount            ; two line fills per row (one at the top, one at the bottom)
MirrorWrite:    LDA CurrentLine            ; get the row number to fill next
                LDX #$FF
FindBankLoop:   INX
                SEC
                SBC #6
                BCS FindBankLoop           ; find which bank of 6 rows the target row resides in

                ADC #6
                TAY                        ; calculate the row number relative to the start of the bank
                CLC
RowIdxLoop:     ADC #40
                DEY
                BPL RowIdxLoop
                TAY                        ; get an index to the end of the row (actually start of subsequent row)

FillLine:       DEX
                BPL TryBank1               ; continue if row is not in first bank

                TAX                        ; get index to the end of the row
                LDA #Char_color

LineColorBank0: DEX
                STA ScreenC_Address_0_5,X  ; set a character colour
                BNE LineColorBank0         ; fill the line with the desired colour

                LDA #CharVal
                
LineTextBank0:  DEY 
                STA Screen_Address_0_5,Y   ; write the screen code to screen RAM
                BNE LineTextBank0          ; fill the line with the character
                BEQ EndLineFill            ; absolute branch - finish with the current line

; same thing but in the second bank of six character rows
TryBank1:       DEX
                BPL TryBank2

                TAX
                LDA #Char_color

LineColorBank1: DEX
                STA ScreenC_Address_6_11,X
                BNE LineColorBank1

                LDA #CharVal
                
LineTextBank1:  DEY 
                STA Screen_Address_6_11,Y
                BNE LineTextBank1
                BEQ EndLineFill
   
; same thing but in the third bank of six character rows             
TryBank2:       DEX
                BPL TryBank3

                TAX
                LDA #Char_color

LineColorBank2: DEX
                STA ScreenC_Address_12_17,X
                BNE LineColorBank2

                LDA #CharVal
                
LineTextBank2:  DEY 
                STA Screen_Address_12_17,Y
                BNE LineTextBank2
                BEQ EndLineFill
      
; same thing but in the fourth bank of six character rows      
TryBank3:       DEX
                BPL DoLine24

                TAX
                LDA #Char_color

LineColorBank3: DEX
                STA ScreenC_Address_18_23,X
                BNE LineColorBank3

                LDA #CharVal
                
LineTextBank3:  DEY 
                STA Screen_Address_18_23,Y
                BNE LineTextBank3
                BEQ EndLineFill

; same thing but in the fifth bank of six character rows
DoLine24:       TAX
                LDA #Char_color

Line24Color:    DEX
                STA ScreenC_Address_24,X
                BNE Line24Color

                LDA #CharVal
                
Line24Text:     DEY 
                STA Screen_Address_24,Y
                BNE Line24Text

EndLineFill:    SEC
                LDA #24
                SBC CurrentLine
                STA CurrentLine        ; mirror the current line in the bottom half of the screen (or switch back to the top half)
                DEC MirrorCount
                BEQ Cont1
                JMP MirrorWrite        ; fill the line in the bottom half of the screen
Cont1:          INC CurrentLine        ; move to the next row
                DEC HowManyRows
                BEQ Cont2
                JMP Next_row           ; fill the specified number of rows
Cont2:          RTS
```

EDIT:
Thirty seconds after posting this answer, I thought of a much cleaner way of doing this, still without using the zero-page. I realized I could use inline pointers to the start of the row in screen RAM and colour RAM. This shortens the code considerably.

```
.VAR ScreenC_Address = $D8            ; color RAM base page
.VAR Screen_Address = $04             ; screen RAM base page

; this is what you are filling your line with
; these are constants - you need to reassemble to change them
; an alternative is to store these in memory and set then set 
; them in code before calling the function   
.VAR Char_color = 3                    ; color constant (cyan)
.VAR CharVal = $20                     ; fill character display code (space)

; set these values to whatever you want before calling the function
CurrentLine:    .DB 0                  ; first row number to fill (0 – 24)
HowManyRows:    .DB 4                  ; count of rows to fill at top and bottom

MirrorCount:    .DB                    ; so code doesn't have to be duplicated for top/bottom halves

Next_row:       LDA #2
                STA MirrorCount        ; two line fills per row (one at the top, one at the bottom)
MirrorWrite:    LDA #0
                TAY
                LDX CurrentLine
                CLC
                BEQ SetPointers
PtrAdjLoop:     ADC #40
                BCC SkipHigh
                INY
                CLC
SkipHigh:       DEX
                BNE PtrAdjLoop         ; calculate 16-bit index to start of row in YA
SetPointers:    STA InlPtrColor+1
                STY InlPtrColor+2
                STA InlPtrScreen+1
                STY InlPtrScreen+2

                LDA #ScreenC_Address
                ADC InlPtrColor+2
                STA InlPtrColor+2      ; set inline color RAM pointer to start of row

                LDA #Screen_Address
                ADC InlPtrScreen+2
                STA InlPtrScreen+2     ; set inline screen RAM pointer to start of row

                LDA #Char_color
                LDY #39
InlPtrColor:    STA $FFFF,Y            ; $FFFF is arbitrary default value for color RAM pointer
                DEY
                BPL InlPtrColor

                LDA #CharVal
                LDY #39
InlPtrScreen:   STA $FFFF,Y            ; $FFFF is arbitrary default value for screen RAM pointer
                DEY
                BPL InlPtrScreen

                SEC
                LDA #24
                SBC CurrentLine
                STA CurrentLine        ; mirror the current line in the bottom half of the screen (or switch back to the top half)
                DEC MirrorCount
                BNE MirrorWrite        ; fill the line in the bottom half of the screen
                INC CurrentLine        ; move to the next row
                DEC HowManyRows
                BNE Next_row           ; fill the specified number of rows
                RTS
```